# How to break my loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I want to have the loop add `integers` to the list and `break` when the user hits return.

How do I manage to do this?

```
lstScore = []
count = 0

while count >= 0:
    count = int(input("Enter a score :"))
    if count != int:
        break   
    elif:
        lstScore.append(int(count))
```

Comment: Do you want it to end when the user presses the return key?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you,added exception handling for int conversion errors

```
lstScore = []
count = 0

while count >= 0:
    try:
        temp = input("Enter a score :")
        if(temp != ''):
            count = int(temp)
        else:
            break
        lstScore.append(int(count))
    except ValueError as x:
        print("value error")
        break
```